# dump methods from shared libraries

Tags: linux, shell, pipe

to list all methods from a shared library I use the

```
objdump -T shared_library.so
```

what has an output like this:

```
00013318 g    DF .text  00000020  Base        apr_os_dir_get
0001afc0 g    DF .text  000000f8  Base        apr_socket_send
00020808 g    DF .text  00000004  Base        apr_shm_create_ex
```

But when I try to pipe the output of **find** into **objdump** like this

```
find ./lib -name "*.so" | objdump -T
```

I get this error:

```
objdump: 'a.out': No such file
```

and this **lib** folder does contain a lot of shared library files.

What is wrong with my command?

SK

Comment: You don’t need the `./` in `./lib`. You only need to include `./` when running a binary located in the current directory (e.g. if `objdump` was in the current directory: `./objdump -T shared_library.so`), not for any arguments of a command. In this case, you can simply say `find lib -name "*.so" ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find ./lib -name "*.so" | xargs objdump -T
```

or

```
find ./lib -name "*.so" -exec objdump -T {} +
```

`objdump` expects the name of the library to be passed on the command line. However, piping the output of `find` to it sends the filenames to `objdump`’s standard input, which it ignores. If you don’t give `objdump` a filename on the command line, it defaults to looking for one named `a.out`, which is the default output filename of some compilers and linkers.

There are a couple ways to use the files found by `find` as parameters to `objdump`.

## `xargs`

`xargs` reads from standard input and then runs another command with what it read from standard input as that command’s arguments. In this case, the filenames in the output of `find` will be piped to `xargs`, which will concatenate them into a single line, append it to the command argument from its own command line, and run that. For example, if the `lib` folder contains the three files `libone.so`, `libtwo.so`, and `libthree.so`, `xargs` will run the command `objdump -T libone.so libtwo.so libthree.so`.

Some commands do not accept multiple filenames at a time, and must instead be called multiple times with only a single filename argument. To do this, pass `-n1` to `xargs`, e.g. `find ./lib -name "*.so" | xargs -n1 objdump -T`. With the above example files, `xargs` would run `objdump -T libone.so`, then `objdump -T libtwo.so`, and then `objdump -T libthree.so`. (Though `objdump` does accept multiple filename arguments, so it is not necessary in this case unless the `lib` folder contains so many files that you’re worried about exceeding the maximum command line length.)

## `find -exec`

`find` has its own option to run commands and pass the filenames it found as command-line arguments. The `-exec` option accepts a command, and replaces the string `{}` with the filename or filenames found, with `+` indicating the end of the command to run.

If you want to run the command multiple times with only a single filename, like `xargs -n1` does, use `\;` instead of `+` in the command: `find ./lib -name "*.so" -exec objdump -T {} \;`.

Comment: How about the simplest: `objdump -T lib/*.so`?

Comment: @Robᵩ That won’t find files recursively.

Comment: Clear! I got the point and I am grateful. This explanation should be part of the manual :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `xargs` or `-exec`. Also, `nm` instead of `objdump` is slightly faster if you're not interested in the extra info that `objdump` provides.

```
find /lib -name \*.so -print0 |xargs -0 nm -D
find /lib -name \*.so -exec nm -D {} +
```

Comment: I tried these commands also and I find them useful, too. Thank you.